# A question involving dead cats

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

This is the most enigmatic and shortest puzzle I have come up with, I will give you two words that hints a person's name, and you will guess what it is.

The name is 9 letters long, and you will need to make 4 logical jumps to get there. All 4 stages are linked, and you need to replace 2 letters in the third stage to get the final answer.

***Murdered Cat***

---

You are on the right track if the last 3 stages are all 9 letters long.

Together the three stages have 14 unique letters.

---

Hint:

> The two words point to an English idiom 21 letters long.

Comment: Maybe a valid hint to the hint? rot13(Phevbfvgl xvyyrq gur png)

Comment: @lukas.j You got the first one right.

Comment: Coincidence or not? rot13(Gur uvag unf sbhegrra havdhr yrggref. Gur guerr sbyybjvat fgntrf unir gbtrgure sbhegrra havdhr yrggref. Jbaqre vs gurl ner gur fnzr?)

Comment: @lukas.j It is a coincidence. (Gur frpbaq uvag funerf avar pbagvahbhf yrggref jvgu gur arkg uvag)

Answer (score 4):

We start with Murdered Cat

The first logical jump is

> to find alliterative synonyms of the same length:
>  Killed Kitten

The second logical jump is

> to find shorter synonyms of the same length:
>  Done Lion

Per the puzzle, the third logical jump

> is to replace two letters, with a slight anagram, and some rhyme
>  Tone Loan

The fourth logical jump is

> once again synonyms
>  Hue Grant

So the person is

> Hugh Grant!

Comment: My answer is probably right but coincidentally a few hours ago [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117133) was posted asking how to help guide solvers of a puzzle involving 3 logical jumps between a specified beginning and ending state. Here we have 4 logical jumps from a specified beginning state to an UNspecified ending state constricted only by it being a person's name. In the unlikely case that my answer is wrong, it only goes to show how open such a puzzle is to unintended valid answers.

Comment: BTW +1 and am looking forward to the real answer if mine isn't it ;)

Comment: You missed it, the answer is not Hugh Grant.